# Schengen overstay penalty and then becoming EU citizen

Tags: eu-citizens, schengen, dual-citizenship, overstay

I am a Brazilian citizen currently in the Netherlands on a tourist visa. I have already had a favorable court decision granting me Italian citizenship almost a year ago. The problem is, they are taking forever to register me as a citizen born abroad, which would allow me to get a birth certificate, ID and passport. As my tourist visa is about to expire, my question is: is there a way of staying legally in the Netherlands in the meantime? If not, what would happen if I overstayed my tourist visa but then became an Italian citizen and just registered as a resident in the Netherlands?

Comment: If you manage to escape detection between the expiration of your tourist visa an the receipt of your Italian citizenship, I doubt they'd impose any penalty for the overstay during that period, but I could be wrong.  More importantly, as a matter of law, does "a favorable court decision granting you Italian citizenship" mean that you are already an Italian citizen but the administrative formalities haven't been completed yet, or does your Italian citizenship only commence on the successful conclusion of the registration you mention?